# Authorization server customizing the access token response to add additional params

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization

I need to add in the json, some user information like id and firstname. It would look like this:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJraWQiOiJmN2Y0MDk0OS04ZjAxLTRj",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 864000,
    "userId": 2,
    "firstname": "Paul"
}
```

where id and firstname are extra data.

```
@Bean
    public OAuth2TokenGenerator<? extends OAuth2Token> tokenGenerator() {
        NimbusJwtEncoder jwtEncoder = new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource());
        JwtGenerator jwtGenerator = new JwtGenerator(jwtEncoder);
        jwtGenerator.setJwtCustomizer(tokenCustomizer());
        OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator accessTokenGenerator = new OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator();
        return new DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator(jwtGenerator, accessTokenGenerator);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer() {
        return context -> {
            OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken principal = context.getPrincipal();
            CustomUserAuthorities customUserAuthorities = (CustomUserAuthorities) principal.getDetails();

            List<String> authorities = customUserAuthorities.getAuthorities().stream().map(x -> x.getAuthority()).toList();
            if (context.getTokenType().getValue().equals("access_token")) {
                Long id = userRepository.findIdByEmail(customUserAuthorities.getUsername());
                String firstname = userRepository.findFirstnameByEmail(customUserAuthorities.getUsername());

                context.getClaims()
                        .claim("id", id)
                        .claim("firstname", firstname)

                        .claim("authorities", authorities)
                        .claim("username", customUserAuthorities.getUsername())
                        .build();
            }
        };
    }
```

In the code above, the .claim is responsible for adding 'firstname' inside the encrypted token, however I want it to be just in the json.